# Microwave sparking

Tags: safety, microwave-oven

Someone put a metal thing in microwave and it began sparking. I cleaned it and was OK.

After a while I put something in the highest degree for 5 minutes and apparently it was too much for the food it began sparking again.
Now its OK with the medium degree I have not examined the high one again.

Do you think the "Magnetron" is OK?

Comment: Normally the only thing that sparks in the microwave is metal. Some dishes have small amounts of metallic paint on them that could be a problem. Make sure the dishes you use are "microwave safe".

Comment: Where exactly is it sparking? If sparking is between the magnetron and chassis, you need to get it fixed or replace the whole thing. If the HV capacitor is sparking, replace the capacitor.

Comment: Non-metallic grape sparking in microwave: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrY0aC81wxI. I prefer the far more spectacular CD in microwave  experiment. You can also make plasma balls using a match/candle with a bowl over it. None of these procedures normally "wreck" a microwave. You can also use a microwave to smelt iron or silver, without destroying the unit.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your comments. I changed the wave guide cover it is working fine now. hoping that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To test the oven put 500 mL of  water in a 1 L glass measuring cup and microwave on high for 2 minutes. If there is sparking, the microwave oven is damaged. If there is no sparking, the oven is almost certainly OK.